# Taggim in a Get

Tags: halacha, divorce

A Get is called a "sefer". In that case, why doesn't it require taggin (beautification marks atop the letters)?

Comment: https://moderntoraleadership.wordpress.com/2020/12/31/may-one-write-a-ketubah-in-stam-script/

Comment: What does "sefer" have to do with anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that a get is called **ספר** כריתות has definitely brought it into discussions in shas and meforshim as to which elements of כתיבה we normally find in סת"ם make (or don't make their way) into the world of writing gittin.

The following places seem to say that tagin are not required in the writing of a get.

The Mahara"l MiPrague in [באר הגולה - באר ד י״א](https://www.sefaria.org/Be%27er_HaGolah%2C_Well_4.11.1?lang=he) says that the Torah gets tagin since it's on a higher level than other things:

> ומפני שהתורה היא יותר עליון ולכך יש על האותיות שבה תגין, לומר לך שאין מעלה אחריה עוד. ואף על גב דפירוש 'היה קושר כתרים לאותיות', כי האות מצד עצמו, כמו שעטנ"ז ג"ץ, צריכים תגין (מנחות כט:), ושאר אותיות אינם צריכים תגין. מפני שהתורה עליון על כל, כמו שהתבאר, ולכך צריכים האותיות שבה, דהיינו אותיות שעטנ"ז ג"ץ, הראוי אל התגין, צריך להיות להם תגין. **ואין צריך תגין בגט** ושאר כתיבה, כי אם בתורה, לפי מעלת התורה צריכין האותיות תגין. הרי התגין בתורה לומר, שהתורה היא סדר אלקי שאין אחריו עוד. ולכך הקב"ה היה קושר תגין לאותיות, כי התג הזה והכתר הזה שהוא יתברך קושר, אין על זה עוד.

Also see a discussion by Rav Aharon Lichtenstein zt"l on this topic in the section **תגים בגט** [in pp 126,127 here](https://etzion.org.il/sites/default/files/Gittin08-dinim_shonim_beketivat_get.pdf) (pp 12,13 of the PDF) where he brings mekoros that show there seems to be a consensus among the rishonim that tagin are not required for a get since tagin flow from a need for כתיבה תמה which exists for סת"ם but not for gittin.
[image]

Comment: Great find! Maybe include in the answer what the Beer HaHolah writes, since links might get invalid over time.

Comment: Good point @Shmuel - just added in the original content.

Comment: The question was "why" not "is there". Why aren't there taggim?

Comment: Double AA - just edited with an attempt to summarize the "why"s. For nuanced details, best to read the quoted sources which delve into the whys.